# MySQL : Create table comparison product

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

I am confused when will display product comparison table. I have 2 tables `t_product_item` and `t_product_specification`. Here's a picture of the table structure:
[image: pic 1]

I want to display a product comparison like this picture :

[image: pic 2]

**Script:**

```
<table border="1">
    <tr style="background-color: #C3C3C3">
        <td>Product</td>
        <td>Spec Name</td>
        <td>Spec Value</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT item, spec_name, spec_value FROM t_product_item JOIN t_product_specification USING (item_id)");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0){
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['item']?>
        <td><?php echo $row['spec_name']?>
        <td><?php echo $row['spec_value']?>
    </tr>
    <?php
        }}
    ?>
</table>
```

Instead it appears like this

**Result:**
[image: pic 3]

How do I structure logically or query for the table to display like the example pic?

Comment: Are you get your answer?

Comment: until now not yet :(

Comment: Are you try my answer? What is the problem with my answer???

Comment: your answer really helps me but i still confused when implementing in table with while loop

Comment: and what if the data in table t_product_item contents of the data record dynamic, example : item_id 3,4 or 5. it is not possible I change the contents of a query if item_id changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `SQL Query` to:

```
SELECT spec_name,MAX(CASE WHEN ItemId=1 THEN spec_value END)`Samsung Galaxy S8+`
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN ItemId=2 THEN spec_value END)`Samsung Galaxy S8` 
FROM t_product_item JOIN t_product_specification USING (item_id)
GROUP BY spec_name
ORDER BY MIN(spec_Id)
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through `item_id` for each of your `<tr>` rows. Instead you should be looping through `spec_name` for `<tr>`, and for each cell `<td>` loop through the product.

In pseudo code:

```
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>&nbsp;</th> <!-- Empty cell for spacer -->

          for (item in item_list) {
            <th>item.name</th>
          }

        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>

          for (spec in spec_list) {
            <td>spec.name</td>
          }

          for (item in item_list) {
            <td>item.spec[spec.name]</td> <!-- display spec detail of each item -->
          }

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

You might have to restructure your data before looping it through the table.